# Color table element with siunitx S column

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a table with numbers that I have aligned using the S column type provided by the `siunitx` package. I need to make one of the table elements red, but when I do that, the number that is red is no longer aligned.

What is the right way to do this? MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} \centering
    \caption{Table with \texttt{c} column type.}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \hline
        Symbol & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value} \\
        \hline
        $\pi$ & 3.141592654 \\
        $2\pi$ & 6.283185307 \\
        $4\pi$ & 12.56637061 \\
        $8\pi$ & {\color{red}25.13274123} \\
        $e$   & 2.71828182845904524 \\
        $\sqrt{2}$ & 1.41421356237309505 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table} \centering
    \caption{Table with \texttt{S} column type.}
    \begin{tabular}{cS}
        \hline
        Symbol & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Value} \\
        \hline
        $\pi$ & 3.141592654 \\
        $2\pi$ & 6.283185307 \\
        $4\pi$ & 12.56637061 \\
        $8\pi$ & {\color{red}25.13274123} \\
        $e$   & 2.71828182845904524 \\
        $\sqrt{2}$ & 1.41421356237309505 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply remove the braces around the `\color{red}25.13274123`. They are not necessary, and content wrapped in braces are not considered numbers I think, hence not aligned as such.

Also, the `\multicolumn` is not necessary, it is enough to wrap `Value` in braces. The reason, as I understand it, is that the `e` in `Value` could be considered a part of an exponential number, e.g. `3e8`, and `siunitx` will then try to align it. To protect it from alignment, wrap it in braces. This is mentioned in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx), section 4.6 **Tabular material** (the last sentence starting on page 13).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} \centering
    \caption{Table with \texttt{S} column type.}
    \begin{tabular}{cS}
        \hline
        Symbol & {Value} \\
        \hline
        $\pi$ & 3.141592654 \\
        $2\pi$ & 6.283185307 \\
        $4\pi$ & 12.56637061 \\
        $8\pi$ & \color{red}25.13274123 \\
        $e$   & 2.71828182845904524 \\
        $\sqrt{2}$ & 1.41421356237309505 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `siunitx`, by default, will center-set items that are surrounded curly braces, regardless of the contents of the group.

Comment: Well that was so easy, I'm almost embarrassed to have asked the question. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example of a siunitx S column where this coloring not works: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684208/prefix-text-in-front-of-s-column-of-siunitx), see the first answer, the wrong coloring is an open issue.

Comment: @Michael.H Yes it does work, but not together with the `>{\usebox{\saveboxTimes}}` in the column specification. I don't know how to fix that though.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I tried to input the content of the usebox directly in the code. But that leads to error messages. So I do not know what you mean with ´Yes it does work, but not together with the usebox´.

Comment: @Michael.H I mean if you remove `>{\usebox{\saveboxTimes}}` altogether it works. Which doesn't help you, I know. Afraid I don't have any idea how to make it work.