# font color does not work in front of S column of `siunitx`

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

Given is a table with factors from x1 to x1000000000 then x0.1 and x0.01 in the fourth column.

The S column of siunitx takes care of the alignment.

Unexpectedly, however, the font color no longer works in the S column. You can see this in the line with a black background, where x1 is not colored white as desired. Of course it's just a small thing, but all previous attempts by me to change that were unsuccessful.

I check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67135/color-table-element-with-siunitx-s-column?noredirect=1&lq=1) but that does not help. I have @koleygr to thank for a partial solution to my problem.

Why is this and how can it be repaired?

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl, siunitx, tabularx, booktabs, xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\saveboxTimes
\savebox{\saveboxTimes}{$\times\,$}
\begin{tabular}{lcc>{\usebox{\saveboxTimes}}S[table-format={\usebox{\saveboxTimes}11.2},table-align-text-before=false]}
\toprule 
Farbe & 1. Ring & 2. Ring & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{3. Ring}}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\rowcolor{black!60}\color{white}schwarz & \color{white}0 & \color{white}0 & \color{white}1\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{brown!50}braun & 1 & 1 & 10\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{red!50}rot & 2 & 2 & 100\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{orange!50}orange & 3 & 3 & 1000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{yellow!50}gelb & 4 & 4 & 10000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{green!30}grün & 5 & 5 & 100000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{blue!40}blau & 6 & 6 & 1000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{violet!30}violett & 7 & 7 & 10000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{gray!30}grau & 8 & 8 & 100000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{white}weiß & 9 & 9 & 1000000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{ColorGold}gold & - & - & 0.1\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{ColorSilber}silber & - & - & 0.01\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
```

[image]

Comment: Got the tip to put the content of the usebox directly into the code. This leads to error messages. Do not know why.

Answer (score 7):

Switching from `tabularx` to the more adaptable `tabularray` solved the problem neatly. The transformed code is:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \begin{talltblr}[
        caption = Widerstand Farbcodes
        ]{
            colspec = {lcc Q[si={table-format=13.2, table-align-text-before=false},c]},
            cell{2-Z}{4} = {preto=$\times$\space},
            row{1} = {guard},
            row{2} = {bg=black!60, fg=white},
            row{3} = {brown!50},
            row{4} = {red!50},
            row{5} = {orange!50},
            row{6} = {yellow!50},
            row{7} = {green!30},
            row{8} = {blue!40},
            row{9} = {violet!30},
            row{10} = {gray!30},
            row{11} = {white},
%           row{12} = {ColorGold},
%           row{13} = {ColorSilber},
            hline{1,2,Z} = {1pt}
        }
    Farbe   &   1. Ring &   2. Ring &   3. Ring     \\
    schwarz &   0       &   0       &   1           \\
    braun   &   1       &   1       &   10          \\
    rot     &   2       &   2       &   100         \\
    orange  &   3       &   3       &   1000        \\
    gelb    &   4       &   4       &   10000       \\
    grün    &   5       &   5       &   100000      \\
    blau    &   6       &   6       &   1000000     \\
    violett &   7       &   7       &   10000000    \\
    grau    &   8       &   8       &   100000000   \\
    weiß    &   9       &   9       &   1000000000  \\
    gold    &   -       &   -       &   0.1         \\
    silber  &   -       &   -       &   0.01        \\
\end{talltblr}% 

\end{document}
```

*Note:*  Unfortunately the colors ColorGold and ColorSilber generated errors (not recognized), so these are commented out in their respective row descriptions.

[image: Resistance values]

Comment: You might want to change the caption to `Kennzeichnung von Widerständen` =) ... nice solution!

Comment: How can I get rid of the caption? It should be noted that the headline should neither shown nor that the caption counter should incremented. Found `\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}` here
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71169502/how-to-remove-contfoot-conthead-caption-in-longtblr-package) The caption disappears, but the table caption counter is incremeted. The next caption number is one more than it should be. I need a global solution, because I set my captions the old fashion way with the caption command in the rest of the document.

Comment: To remove the caption from the table, you can just comment out the caption entry inside the square brackets. Adding `label=none` in that section will prevent the numbering of the table and the increase of the table counter (according to page 39 of the manual of `tabularray`)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I think a problem of your code is that you place the `$\times$` inside a `\savebox` which essentially prevents the contents from being affected by `\color` settings outside of this box. I would therefore suggest that you don't use such a box in this case.

I don't fully understand why the coloring becomes broken. Somehow, the `siunitx` package seems not to be able to process a `\color` command if this is not the only thing which is placed before the number in the cell that should be formatted. If you place something like `\color{white}\times` in front of a number in an `S` type cell, only the stuff before the number will be affected by the `\color` setting, but not the formatted number.

Compare the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor, siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format={{\times}2.2}]
}
\color{red} 99.99 \\
\color{red}\times 99.99 \\
\end{tabular}% 
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it is possible to use the option `color` to set the color for the formatted number. You only need to set the correct value in one of the cells before the `S` type cell. For example like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{colortbl, siunitx, booktabs, xcolor}

\def\Scolcolor{black}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    l c c 
    >{\color{\Scolcolor}\times\,}S[
        table-format={{\times\,}11.2}, 
        table-align-text-before=false, 
        color=\Scolcolor
    ]
}
\toprule 
Farbe & 1. Ring & 2. Ring & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{3. Ring}}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\rowcolor{black!60}\gdef\Scolcolor{white}%
    \color{white}schwarz & \color{white}0 & \color{white}0 & 1\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{brown!50}\gdef\Scolcolor{black}%
    braun  & 1 & 1 & 10\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{red!50}rot & 2 & 2 & 100\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{orange!50}orange & 3 & 3 & 1000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{yellow!50}gelb & 4 & 4 & 10000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{green!30}grün & 5 & 5 & 100000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{blue!40}blau & 6 & 6 & 1000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{violet!30}violett & 7 & 7 & 10000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{gray!30}grau & 8 & 8 & 100000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{white}weiß & 9 & 9 & 1000000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{yellow!10}gold & - & - & 0.1\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{gray!10}silber & - & - & 0.01\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}% 
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you are not bound to use a regular `tabular`, you could also try the `nicematrix` package (but, here as well, you need to un-box the `\times` in order to make things work):

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix, booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand{\timesprefix}{}{%
    \ensuremath\times\,%
}
\begin{NiceTabular}{
    l c c 
    >{\timesprefix}S[table-format={{\timesprefix}11.2}, table-align-text-before=false]
}
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolor{black!60}{2}
    \rowcolor{brown!50}{3}
    \rowcolor{red!50}{4}
    \rowcolor{orange!50}{5}
    \rowcolor{yellow!50}{6}
    \rowcolor{green!30}{7}
    \rowcolor{blue!40}{8}
    \rowcolor{violet!30}{9}
    \rowcolor{gray!30}{10}
    \rowcolor{white}{11}
    \rowcolor{yellow!10}{12}
    \rowcolor{gray!10}{13}
\Body
\toprule 
Farbe & 1. Ring & 2. Ring & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{3. Ring}}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\RowStyle[color=white]{}
schwarz & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
braun & 1 & 1 & 10 \\
rot & 2 & 2 & 100 \\
orange & 3 & 3 & 1000 \\
gelb & 4 & 4 & 10000 \\
grün & 5 & 5 & 100000 \\
blau & 6 & 6 & 1000000 \\
violett & 7 & 7 & 10000000 \\
grau & 8 & 8 & 100000000 \\
weiß & 9 & 9 & 1000000000 \\
gold & - & - & 0.1 \\
silber & - & - & 0.01 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}% 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some other packages that provide macros to set the text color for the whole row could also be of use.

Comment: nice answer, sorry I did not read it before posting mine... about "a `\savebox` which essentially prevents the contents from being affected by `\color` "  I think you can remove the "essentially" because `\savebox` hard-codes a reset to "current color" i.e. color *at time of definition* at very start of the box. At least this is my understanding of the `\color@setgroup->\begingroup \set@color` and `\set@color->\special {color push \current@color }\aftergroup \reset@color`. (which is all done *at time of definition* so the TeX box contains the `color push/pop` specials with a set color)

Answer (score 4):

Use a `\multicolumn` to redefine the column type for that cell.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl, siunitx, tabularx, booktabs, xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\saveboxTimes
\savebox{\saveboxTimes}{$\times\,$}
\begin{tabular}{lcc>{\usebox{\saveboxTimes}}S[table-format={\usebox{\saveboxTimes}11.2},table-align-text-before=false]}
\toprule 
Farbe & 1. Ring & 2. Ring & \multicolumn{1}{c}{{3. Ring}}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\rowcolor{black!60}\color{white}schwarz & \color{white}0 & \color{white}0 &
% HERE ARE THE CHANGES
\multicolumn{1}{S[table-format={{$\times\,$}11.2},table-align-text-before=false,color=white]}{\textcolor{white}{$\times\,$}1}%
% END OF CHANGES
\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{brown!50}braun & 1 & 1 & 10\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{red!50}rot & 2 & 2 & 100\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{orange!50}orange & 3 & 3 & 1000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{yellow!50}gelb & 4 & 4 & 10000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{green!30}grün & 5 & 5 & 100000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{blue!40}blau & 6 & 6 & 1000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{violet!30}violett & 7 & 7 & 10000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{gray!30}grau & 8 & 8 & 100000000\tabularnewline
\rowcolor{white}weiß & 9 & 9 & 1000000000\tabularnewline
%\rowcolor{ColorGold}gold & - & - & 0.1\tabularnewline
%\rowcolor{ColorSilber}silber & - & - & 0.01\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}% 
\end{document}
```

I commented out the last two rows as this preamble does not define the `ColorGold` and `ColorSilber` in my locale.

[image: colored table with S column and special cell]

Comment: Reading it only now It may be that this is quite related to [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/684698/293669)  by @JasperHabicht

Comment: This is also a nice approach. The approach is indeed similar, as you also colorize the `\times` and the numbers separately (which is, I guess, the only way to go if one wants to stick to a regular `tabular`).